# How can I resize (not compress) multiple images in a MS Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, images

In a blank document, I insert images (screenshots - all are of same size and same format) from a folder. I want to resize the images to a desired size. All now I am doing is selecting one image by one, setting its size. Word does not seem to have multiselect working for images.

Ideally, I want to select multiple images set its size in one go with out use of a macro.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You have multiple way to do this:

**1- Try using a macro** with the following code:

```
Sub resize()
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument
    For i = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count
        With .InlineShapes(i)
            .ScaleHeight = 50
            .ScaleWidth = 50
        End With
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

**2- Resize all images to the same height and width:**

a. Right click first image, open 'Size and Position' box (or open box from the Picture -> Format -> Size box. You need the size box, not just the height and width options in the tab, to disable the lock aspect ratio or this won't work)
b. Disable 'Lock Aspect Ratio'
c. Change height and width to desired size
d. Close box
e. Click on next image and hit F4. Continue by clicking on sequential images and hitting F4 (For MAC use "command - Y").
f. For large documents, use the vertical scroll bar on the right-hand side to move between images

**3- Uniform aspect ratio for all images**
a. Right click first image, open 'Size and Position' box (or open box from the Picture -> Format -> Size box).
b. Change the aspect ratio % value
c. Close box
d. Click on the next image and hit F4. Note, the aspect ratio value wasn't changed to exactly the same value for all images, but was close (53 % instead of 50%) so the macro way is more precise

**4- Or using third-party plugins** for MS Word like [KUTools](http://www.extendoffice.com/download/kutools-for-word.html)

Comment: Thanks. Your first suggestion of using macro is not an option for me. Your second suggestion does not seem to work; hitting F4 does not seem to do anything. Your third option is also same as second as far as F4 key is concerned.  Based on my exploration I see [this](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/1207-word-resize-all-multiple-images.html) link where it clearly says multi select doesnt work and points to KUTools only.

Comment: I checked the solutions 1,2,3. All of them works correctly.

Comment: My apologies; I overlooked the step of unlocking the aspect ratio as I do not want my images to go skewed. Rather I left locked, changed the width and set the aspect ration unlocked and F4 key worked. Bizarre!

Comment: OP asks about resizing. I think Razavi answers that correctly, here. But for others: if it's just a matter of image size (in memory)/resolution , maybe ["Compress Pictures" would work](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Reduce-the-file-size-of-a-picture-8db7211c-d958-457c-babd-194109eb9535) . It seems "Compress Pictures" can work against ALL images in a doc, rather than one-at-a-time. I assumed it could only do one-at-a-time, which is why I came here.

Comment: The 2nd solution is just great! Working with MS Office for ages but never came across that F4 key! Some additional information: https://techforluddites.com/f4-the-magic-ms-office-key-no-one-knows-about/

Comment: Thanks a ton!! For MAC users use "command - Y" instead of F4

Answer (score 10):

Set the way you use pictures from "In Line With Text" to "Top and Bottom". Resize your 1st picture as desired In Format Pictures. Then  select pictures one at a time and press F4. Not exactly instant but way better than trying to do them one at a time in the Format box.

The reformatting of IN LINE WITH TEXT to one of the other options is essential for the F4 to work.

Answer (score 4):

If you save your document as .docx, then you will be able to open it as zip-archive. There will be media folder with all images (mine had PNG images). You can then use programs like IrfanView, XnViewMP, FastStone Viewer to perform batch transformations like resize, reduce color depth, etc. Pack your images back into zip and rename it to docx.

For example, in my docx full of screenshots I needed to reduce number of colors to 8, which is enough for documentation purposes. After processing my 10MB doc became 1.8MB doc, so savings can be significant. Always save your original docx in case you want to restore pictures after too much degradation/processing etc.

For people who have issues with unzip/zip, here are the steps:

```
rename mydoc.docx mydoc.zip
mkdir mydoc_unzip
cd mydoc_unzip
unzip ../mydoc.zip
... manipulate ....
zip -a ../new_doc.zip *
cd ..
rename new_doc.zip new_doc.docx
```

I use a tool called Total Commander which allows me go directly inside docx file (Ctrl-PgDn), then I unpack(copy) media folder to temp location, do my manipulation, and copy media files back using Total Commander.

Once you rename docx to zip you should be able to explore it using Windows File Explorer - the steps will be as with Total Commander - copy media folder outside to temp location, manipulate images, copy them back into zip.

Comment: Wow what a different approach!

Comment: I just tried this but got an error after rezipping "...there are problems with the contents". Word are missing some parts.

I have also tried just unzipping and rezipping - that also failed.

I am using 7zip. Any suggestions?

Comment: I had a similar error message and did the repair thing, but it was just down to a change in filename. e.g. Although word renames the filename itself, it does not change the extension. So in my case, I had a mix of jpg and jpeg. When I batch resized them all, they all changed to jpg. Thus only those which were originally jpg showed. The rest were broken.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to resize multiple images in a MS Word document which was converted from a PDF document and the multiple images, which form the Word actually, are out of margins of pages of Word, here is the solution.

1. To save Word as web page (*.html)
2. To click Type in the folder that created automatically in the process above and find images you need, sorting them in order.
   [enter image description here][1]
3. To create a new blank Word. Meanwhile, you can change Margins in Page Layout of Word.
4. To select images sorted and drag them into the new blank Word.
5. They fit perfectly. :)

Sometimes the order is converse and you can drag them again. Maybe it is related to the operation of selecting images.

Comment: The question describes inserting images into a blank document rather than converting from a PDF.  It also doesn't mention anything about them being outside margins.  This doesn't seem to really address what was asked in the question.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: The image is missing.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your pictures are not "Inline with text", all you have to do is CTRL+Click on each one to select them, and then you can resize them individually with the selection handles.

Once they're selected, anything you do will affect all of them - size, set the text wrapping, outline color, fill color, toggle the Lock Aspect Ratio, any attribute really.

Comment: This works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do really is the following:

1. Take a blank document
2. Go to page layout -> columns-> two columns
3. Drag the pictures onto the page

It will automatically resize.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to make batch inserted images all the same width without using a Macro.

Assuming you want the images to be **3.5** inches wide

1. Open a blank document.
2. Page layout > Set custom margin > Left = 0, Right = 8.5-**3.5** = 5 inches.
3. Insert all images either via drag & drop or toolbar. All of them should automatically be resized to 3.5 inches wide.
4. Reset the margin to desired value, or copy to somewhere else.